# How to send pointer in struct in MPI

Tags: c, pointers, struct, mpi

I have struct like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    double *y;
    int **z;
}
ind;
```

how could I send pointer like *y and **z via MPI to other processes? I know that many answers said that never send pointers by MPI. But if I cannot change *y to an array because it is used in other part of the main program, what should I do to transfer them through processes via MPI? Especially for **z, how should I do ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would imagine that you can't. Say one process modified `*y`, how would the other processes know that `*y` changed?

Comment: You cannot send a pointer because it is meaningless outside of the process in which it was allocated. If you want to send the array of data to which it points, ask that question instead.

Comment: Sorry. I am new in programming. Maybe I did not describe the question clearly. I do want to send the array of data to which it points. Could you give a little clue for this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just following the code from the second example [here](http://geco.mines.edu/workshop/class2/examples/mpi/index.html), I did the following. I believe this is what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int *send, *recv;
  int rank, i;
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

  send = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
  recv = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);

  for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    send[i] = 5*i;

  if (rank == 0)
    MPI_Send(send, 10, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  else {
    MPI_Recv(recv, 10, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
      printf("%d\n", recv[i]);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Running it outputs,

```
$ mpiexec -n 2 mpi_test
0
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
```

Now you just have to adapt it to your own problem.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. What if I want to build a MPI_struct to include all the elements in the ind struct and send them as an MPI_type? How to handle the pointers? Especially, how to calculate the MPI_address of those arrays which points by the pointers?

Comment: If you are referring to http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Type_create_struct.html, then I will say that you can't directly. What I would recommend is creating a separate function (you can model after MPI if you like) that ships your data structure as I posted. A bunch of Send/Recv/Broadcast/etc. to properly transfer your data structure. That will work.

Comment: You could also have that function serialize your data by packing it into a buffer which can be unpacked on the receiving side.