# How to use MPI to transfer a custom struct with a dynamic array？

Tags: c, arrays, struct, mpi

There is a simple example to describe my question.
I have a custom struct which contains a dynamic array

```
struct my_data_type {
    int c;
    int d[];
};
```

and  the root process (process 0) has an array of such struct `nums[4]`.

I want to send chunks of the array to different processes (for example, 2 processes) via `MPI_Scatter`. The main problem here is that I want this array `d[]` to be dynamic.

The main code is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int my_size; MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_size);
    int my_rank; MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    int len = 2; //example: the dynamic array d contains len=2 elements
    my_data_type *nums //nums[4]
        = (my_data_type*)malloc((sizeof(my_data_type) + sizeof(int) * len) * 4);
    my_data_type *sub_nums //sub_nums[2]
        = (my_data_type*)malloc((sizeof(my_data_type) + sizeof(int) * len) * 2);

    if (my_rank == 0) { //just some examples
        nums[0].c = 0; nums[1].c = 1; nums[2].c = 2; nums[3].c = 3;
        nums[0].d[0] = 10; nums[1].d[0] = 11; nums[2].d[0] = 12; nums[3].d[0] = 13;
        nums[0].d[1] = 14; nums[1].d[1] = 15; nums[2].d[1] = 16; nums[3].d[1] = 17;
    }

    MPI_Datatype mpi_data_type; //new datatype
    int blocklens[2];
    MPI_Datatype old_types[2];
    MPI_Aint indices[2];

    blocklens[0] = 1; blocklens[1] = len;
    old_types[0] = MPI_INT; old_types[1] = MPI_INT;
    MPI_Address(&nums[0].c, &indices[0]);
    MPI_Address(&nums[0].d[0], &indices[1]);
    indices[1] = indices[1] - indices[0];
    indices[0] = 0;

    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blocklens, indices, old_types, &mpi_data_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_data_type);

    MPI_Scatter(nums, 2, mpi_data_type,
                sub_nums, 2, mpi_data_type,
                0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    cout << "rank " << my_rank << ": " << endl;
    cout << "c: " << sub_nums[0].c << ", " << sub_nums[1].c << endl;
    cout << "d: " << sub_nums[0].d[0] << ", " << sub_nums[0].d[1] << ", ";
    cout << sub_nums[1].d[0] << ", " << sub_nums[1].d[1] << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

If I change the `int d[];` into `int d[2];` in the definition of struct `my_data_type`, I will certainly get the expected results like

```
rank 0: 
c: 0, 1
d: 10, 14, 11, 15
rank 1: 
c: 2, 3
d: 12, 16, 13, 17
```

But if not, the results are the following:

```
rank 0: 
c: 0, 10
d: 10, 14, 14, 15
rank 1: 
c: 33, 0
d: 0, 0, 0, 1
```

As you can see, I know the problem is about the dynamic array, but I cannot use a static one in my project. So how can I change my code above to get the expected results?

Comment: If you use `d[]` then `sizeof(...)` is not what you expect, and hence a short malloc and data corruption.

Comment: Dear friend, thanks for your comments. I found a bug and I have updated it (malloc for the struct arrays ```nums[4]``` and ```sub_nums[4]```). But it was still wrong. And I cannot malloc the dynamic array ```d[]``` because array type 'int []' is not assignable.

Comment: I don't think you can do arrays of structs with flexible array members in a sane way.

Comment: I agree with you. So actually I want to know how to handle arrays of structs with flexible array members in another way.

Comment: I updated my answer with how to handle arrays of structs with FAMs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is not mpi but rather the use of arrays of struct with flexible array members.  Here's an example program to illustrate the problem

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct s s;
struct s
{
    int c;
    int d[];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    assert(sizeof(s) == sizeof(int));

    int len = 4;
    s* okay = malloc(sizeof(*okay) + sizeof(int)*len);

    intptr_t true_size = (intptr_t)&okay->d[len] -(intptr_t)(okay);
    assert(true_size == ((len+1)*sizeof(int)));

    int nbad = 6;
    s* bad = malloc((sizeof(*bad) + sizeof(int)*len)*nbad);


    intptr_t bad_size = (intptr_t)&bad[1] -(intptr_t)&bad[0];

    /* this size mismatch means arrays of `s` do not do what you think they do */
    assert(bad_size != true_size);
    assert(bad_size == sizeof(int));

    assert((char*)&bad[1] == (char*)&bad[0].d[0]);
    assert((char*)&bad[2] == (char*)&bad[0].d[1]);
    assert((char*)&bad[3] == (char*)&bad[0].d[2]);

    assert((char*)&bad[1].d[0] == (char*)&bad[0].d[1]);
    assert((char*)&bad[2].d[0] == (char*)&bad[0].d[2]);
    assert((char*)&bad[3].d[0] == (char*)&bad[0].d[3]);
}
```

To handle arrays of structs with flexible array members, you will need to manually compute the memory offsets for indexing rather than relying on the compiler.  So you could define a helper function like this:

```c
s* s_index(const s* a, int len, int index)
{
    uintptr_t true_size = sizeof(*a) + len*sizeof(int);
    return (s*)((char*)a + index * true_size);
}
```

And then use `s_index` to access the desired member of the array, rather than the `bad[0]`, `bad[1]` constructs:

```c
s* first = s_index(bad, len, 0);
s* second = s_index(bad, len, 1);
assert((char*)&first->d[len] == (char *)second);
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help!! You are right and I can adapt it to my own problem.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong on this, but I think what you want is to save a pointer to an array (i.e. `int** myArrPointer`) because I think what you'll need to do, since i don't think that you can allocate an array in C (i.e. `myArr = myOtherArr`), is to:

1. Calculate the size of the new array
2. Allocate memory for that new array
3. Store a pointer to that new array in your struct

Your struct will probably need to end up looking something like this:

```
struct my_data_type 
{
    int ArrSize;
    int** PointerToAnArray;
};

void SomeFunForSwappingArrays(my_data_type* instance, int newArrSize)
{
    int* newArr = (int*)malloc(newArrSize*sizeof(int));
    //free the memory of the old array. if you don't need the data anymore, i would
    //consider doing this.
    free(*(instance->PointerToAnArray));
    //save the memory address of the new array
    instance->PointerToAnArray = &newArr;
    instance->ArrSize = newArrSize;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But the problem is that sending pointers, rather than arrays, to other MPI nodes seems to be meaningless.

Comment: Check this question for sending data via pointers through MPI. It looks like you actually are able to. I haven't heard of MPI until now, so I was curious if this was possible.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217553/how-to-send-pointer-in-struct-in-mpi

Comment: Also, arrays decay into pointers in C anyways when used as function inputs, so to me it doesn't make sense that putting an array into a function would work, while putting a pointer into a function would not. I would think that the function would be using a pointer either way due to the decay.

Comment: I found the pointers actually work, but there is something wrong when I use pointers inside a custom struct. In fact, my opinion is just like the comment by Jeff, said: "You cannot send a pointer because it is meaningless outside of the process in which it was allocated." A memory address of one process is not useful for other processes (in other computers).

Comment: Anyway, I will try to use pointers alone, not in a struct. That will probably work.

Comment: Maybe this will clarify what I meant. I meant that you should send `*( instance->PointerToAnArray)` and not `instance->PointerToAnArray` because, as you noted, sending `instance->PointerToAnArray` is probably going to be meaningless to whever you're sending it to.